# Grab images from another website, like pinterest

Tags: image, pinterest

Im trying to build something like images bookmarklet site like Pinterest, but somehow some of the website doesnt grab any image. Some are works just fine. Also as additional information, I use jquery wookmark as the grid templates.

Here are the codes im currently use... I dont know if its right or simply i used the wrong method to retrieve the images. Cheers guys in advance for any comment or help... really appreciated.

```
-- html
<ul id="tiles"></ul>
<div id="loader">
    <div id="loaderCircle" style="display:none"></div>
</div>

-- javascript
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadData() {
        isLoading      = true;
        var link_pin   ='http://www.somewebsite.com';

        $('#loaderCircle').show();

        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo(base_url('index.php/home/pin_ajax'))?>',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {link_pin:link_pin},
            success: onLoadData
        });
    };

    function onLoadData(data) { 
        isLoading = false;
        $('#loaderCircle').hide();

        var html = '';
        var i=0, length=data.length, returns_data;

        for(; i<length; i++) {
            var link_foto = data[i];    


            var newImg = new Image();
            newImg.src = link_foto;
            var height = newImg.height;
            var width  = newImg.width;

            var image_click="image_clicks('"+link_foto+"')";

            if (width >="200" && height >="200"){
                html += '<li onclick="'+image_click+'" id="image_'+i+'">';
                    html += '<a>';
                        html += '<div class="back_tristlist">';
                            html += '<span class="hover-icon icon-text">&#128269;</span>';
                            html += '<img src="'+link_foto+'">';
                        html += '</div>';
                    html += '</a>';
                html += '<div class="space_image"></div>';
                html += '</li>';
            }
        }

        $('#tiles').append(html);

        handler = $('#tiles li');
        handler.wookmark(options);
    };
</script>

-- php

public function pin_ajax(){
    extract($_GET);

    $page = file_get_contents($link_pin);
    error_reporting(0);
    $doc = new DOMDocument(); 
    @$doc->loadHTML($page);

    $images = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img'); 
    echo($images);
    $_datas[]="";

    foreach($images as $image){
        $raw_img_url = $image->getAttribute('src');
        $img_final_link = $raw_img_url;
        $img_url = explode('http://www.', $raw_img_url);
        $img_check = $img_url[1];

        if($img_check==''){
            $img_url = explode('http://', $raw_img_url);
            $img_check = $img_url[1];
            if($img_check!=''){ $img_check_error=1; }
            if($img_check==''){ $img_check_error=2; }
        }

        $_datas[] = ($img_check);
    }

    $output = json_encode($_datas);
    echo($output);
}
```

Comment: Have you made sure that parenting.com allows deep-linking / leeching images from their site? "Allowing" both in the technical matter and in the question of copyrights?